# How to prove the following using triangle inequality?

Tags: proof-writing, triangle-inequality

Problem: Show that for any $a, b \in ℝ ^n: \|a + b\|\geq\|a\|-\|b\|$

I have a feeling that we can use the triangle inequality here somehow. I am not sure how to start this proof?

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images of text.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.  Oh... and just expand the left-hand-side of the inequality.  The result drops out immediately.

Comment: As for how to continue... you are correct to try to think of the triangle inequality.  Perhaps if we were to rearrange things a bit, $\|a\|\leq \|a+b\|+\|b\|$ this might be a bit more recognizable to you?  What if we were to remind you that $0 = b-b$ and that anything plus "zero" is equal to itself?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "expand the left side", most would think you mean as $\|a+b\|\leq \|a\|+\|b\|$.  That tells us things that $\|a+b\|$ is less than, but not much about what it is greater than.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(a+b)+(-b)=a$. Therefore by the triangle inequality as you suggest,
$$\|a\|=\|(a+b)+(-b)\|\leq\|a+b\|+\|-b\|=\|a+b\|+\|b\|.$$
Rearranging gives your desired result.